# Do Duplo train cars with two female ends exist?

Tags: trains, duplo

Most Duplo train cars have a male and a female connector, such as [Duplo Car Base 2 x 6 with Red Wheels with Fake Bolts and Open Hitch End](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11248c02).

Since most tractors, in the widest meaning of cars meant to pull other cars only have a male ending, such as [Duplo Car Base 4 x 8 with Four Black Wheels and White Hubs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15314c03), you can only make Duplo trains which go one way.

Commuter trains in my city have a cab on each side on the train, meaning that when they are at the terminus, the driver just has to move to the far-end cab, and be on his way. My son would like to build such a train, but cannot connect an other tractor at the end of his train, since it is always male - male.

Are you aware of a female - female train car, that would allow such a two-way train? (Or any other way to achieve this!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any train cars like what you describe.

It sounds like you could get this to work by building one of the locomotives backwards on its base.

For example, here's the locomotive assembly from the [Cargo Train (10875)](https://brickset.com/sets/10875-1/Cargo-Train).

[image: Locomotive assembly]

You could build a second "locomotive" by putting the same orange train chassis on top of the regular [train car base](https://brickset.com/parts/6257289/base-4x8-no-1) backwards:

[image: Train car base]

The train could then be pulled (or pushed) by the real locomotive and the other unpowered locomotive could be attached to the opposite end of the train.

That general technique should work for most trains, but you may have to get a little creative if the parts for the locomotive interfere with the connectors on one of the train wagons.

[image: 10954 Train]